# How to convert my view based application to navigation based application?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

Can anybody explain me the step by step process of converting a view based application to navigation based application?which are the steps taken in both IB and in My appdelegate to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

In your app delegate you can put your code like this:

```
 self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
    [self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];
```

Answer (score 0):

add a UInavigation controller object in the interface file.and then add the code in your didfinishlaunch

```
self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
    //self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
    //self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;



    // Override point for customization after app launch    
    [window addSubview:self.navigationController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

return YES;

and dont forget to connect the delegate to filesowner in IB.